# Non static variable cannot be referenced from static context java

Tags: java

I'm aware this question has been asked many, many times and I've read loads of answers but I can't get my head around how to fix my problem. Here is my code:

```
public class Circle
{
    public int diameter;
    public int xPosition;
    public int yPosition;
    public String color;


    public Circle()
    {
        diameter = 30;
        xPosition = 20;
        yPosition = 60;
        color = "blue";
    }

    public void toString()
    {
        System.out.println("The diameter of the circle is " + Circle.diameter);
        System.out.println("The x position of the circle is " + Circle.xPosition);
        System.out.println("The y position of the circle is " + Circle.yPosition);
        System.out.println("The colour of the circle is " + Circle.color);
    }


   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
        Circle c1 = new Circle();
        c1.toString();

   }

}
```

I did originally fix the issue by changing:

```
public class Circle
{
    public int diameter;
    public int xPosition;
    public int yPosition;
    public String color;
}
```

to

```
public class Circle
{
    public static int diameter;
    public static int xPosition;
    public static int yPosition;
    public static String color;
}
```

Whilst this does work, I feel it's not a good way to do it. I've read something about instance variables but I'm not sure how to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: Note that `public void toString()` is a very bad method name. You should override the `toString()` method from the `Object` class instead. I.e `public String toString()` and return a String that describe your object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is with with `toString()` function:

```
    System.out.println("The diameter of the circle is " + Circle.diameter);
    System.out.println("The x position of the circle is " + Circle.xPosition);
    System.out.println("The y position of the circle is " + Circle.yPosition);
    System.out.println("The colour of the circle is " + Circle.color);
```

You are referencing *non-static* variable with Class reference. Just replace `Circle` with `this`. Have a look [`Understanding Instance and Class member`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) tutorial

**Edit:**

> Strangely, it's not letting me use the name toString() because
>   "toString() in Circle cannot override toString() in object". It works
>   with any other name though

yes because, `toString()` method is declared in `Object` class which is super class for all of the java class. This method has a return type with `String`, where instead you are using `void`. So either you will have to change the return type to `String` or change the function name to anything other.

Comment: Or just `diameter` etc., which is equivalent to `this.diameter`.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan, thank you but isn't referencing the instance with `this` is preferable as a conventional approach.

Comment: @JaAnTr I suggest reading the API documentation for [Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html). All classes extend Object, directly or indirectly, so you cannot have a method with the same name and argument list as any of the Object methods unless it has the same return type.

Comment: Thanks everyone, going to read it all now. I understand it much better.

Comment: @Sage I suppose some shops may require the use of `this.` for referencing fields even when there is no ambiguity, but it does not seem to be a very common convention. It is certainly not followed in the source code for java.lang and java.util classes.

Answer (score 0):

Since Static variables and methods are connected to the class itself and not it's instances
so they called using the class name like:

================================================================================

```
class ABC{
public static int a;

public void A()
{
   System.out.println("The value of a is: "+a);
}

public class test
{
   ABC.a = 10;
   ABC.A();
}
```

You need not to change variables to static variables.

Just call variables using `this` operator.